# Given $f$ is twice-differentiable function and that $f(0), f'(0),f''(0)$ are all negative, which properties does $f$ necessarily have if $f''$ has?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $f$ is twice-differentiable function on the set of real numbers and that $f(0), f'(0),$ and $f''(0)$ are all negative. Suppose that $f''$ has all three of the following properties:

I. It is increasing on the interval $[0,\infty).$

II. It has a unique zero in the interval $[0,\infty)$.

III. It is unbounded on the interval $[0,\infty)$.

Which of the same three properties does $f$ necessarily have?

**My proof:** Since $f''(0)<0$ and $f''$ is increasing and unbounded then there is some $x_0$ such that $f''(x_0)=0$. Hence $f'$ is decreasing for $x<x_0$ and increasing for $x>x_0$ and $f'$ intersects $x$-axis somewhere at $x_1$ (because $f''$ is unbounded, right?). Thus, $f$ decreasing until $x_1$ and then increases.

It is easy to see that property I does not hold for function $f$. But how to show that two other properties are true?